# rspec mock return given args

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is it possible to return the args given  to a stubbed/mocked method with rspec?

I kind of want to write something like this:

`object.should_receive(:foo).with(anything()).and_return(that_thing())`

EDIT:

I realised a way of doing it - the return value of the block is returned by the method call:

`object.should_receive(:foo) { |args| args }`

See "Arbitrary Handling of Received Messages" at http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/message_expectations.html

Perhaps there is another way?

Comment: Using a block like this is exactly the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a substitute implementation to handle and store the argument:

```
that_thing = nil
object.should_receive(:foo).with(anything()) do |arg|
  that_thing = arg
end
```

Comment: Ooh, I realised I misinterpreted your question. Your edit looks like the simplest way to me.